# How do I concat application context in a Tapestry .tml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tapestry

I am developing a web-application with Tapestry and I have a bunch of images that application displays in more than one page, so I wrote the path in WEB-INF/app.properties file.

But I need to concat the context to write the correct path in .tml. When I don't have the path wrote in a .properties, I just write the following code:

```
<img src="${context:relativePath}/>
```

If I have the path in ${messages:imgPath} I am not able to do this:

```
<img src="${context:${message:deleteIconPath}"}
```

I was reading for a while and I think that maybe the solution is in the controller class, but I am not sure.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've been thinking and found a solution: set urls in contex-params on "web.xml".

Then, I define an Asset on controller class:

```
@Property
@Path("context:paramName")
private Asset image;
```

In ".tml" put the src as "${image}".